# Setting priority to intents

Tags: android

I am relatively new to android and I need to find a way to set priorities to an intent...I have seen the intent-filter documentation and the api setPriority....I dont know how to use it. Can you please give me a sample application.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can set priority on `IntentFilter` object(s) that cause these items to be started .use [IntentFilter.setPriority()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29) as for example i want to set priority for `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        filter.setPriority(1000);// what you want to set
```